# Trouble with converting string to integer using ATOI In Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, intel, atoi

I'm trying to read in two strings, convert them into numbers using atoi function, and then print out the result.

Here's my uninitialized variables.  (%define BUFLEN 20)

```
SECTION .bss                    ; uninitialized data section

m:           resb BUFLEN             ;STRING 1
mlen:        resb 4
r:           resb BUFLEN             ;STRING 2
rlen:        resb 4
```

Here's where I get the user input/ attempt allocate it into memory

```
   ; prompt user for FIRST NUMBER

    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write function
    mov     ebx, STDOUT             ; Arg1: file descriptor
    mov     ecx, msg1               ; Arg2: addr of message
    mov     edx, len1               ; Arg3: length of message
    int     080h                    ; ask kernel to write


    ; read in user input
    ;
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ       ; read function
    mov     ebx, STDIN              ; Arg 1: file descriptor
    mov     ecx, m                  ; Arg 2: address of buffer
    mov     edx, BUFLEN                  ; Arg 3: buffer length
    int     080h
    mov     [rlen], eax             ; save length of string read

    ; prompt user for SECOND NUMBER

    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE      ; write function
    mov     ebx, STDOUT             ; Arg1: file descriptor
    mov     ecx, msg2               ; Arg2: addr of message
    mov     edx, len2               ; Arg3: length of message
    int     080h                    ; ask kernel to write

    ; read in user input
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ       ; read function
    mov     ebx, STDIN              ; source
    mov     ecx, r                  ; destination
    mov     edx, BUFLEN                  ; length of destination
    int     080h              
    mov     [mlen], eax             ; save length of string read
```

Now I'm trying to convert the strings using atoi and print them out

```
    ;CONVERT TO #
    mov     eax, 0                  ;zero out register
    mov     eax, m
    call    atoi
    add     esp, 4

    ;PRINT IT
    push    ax
    push    print_r
    call    printf
    add     esp, 8

    ;CONVERT TO #
    mov     eax, 0                  ;zero out register
    mov     eax, r
    call    atoi
    add     esp, 4

    ;PRINT IT
    push    ax
    push    print_r
    call    printf
    add     esp, 8
```

This is my output...

Enter first #: 1234

Enter second#: 1234

Number: 1234

Hanging on second atoi call

Comment: Surely you do not want to `push ax`!

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you're not allocating enough space for the input *and* you're not reading it properly.

If you input the string `12345678`, you need eight bytes for the characters, one for the newline, and one for the terminating `\0`. So, a `RESD 1` is not going to cut the mustard, it only gives you eight bytes rather than ten.

For actually *reading* the information:

```
mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ       ; read function
mov     ebx, STDIN              ; Arg 1: file descriptor
mov     ecx, m                  ; Arg 2: address of buffer
mov     edx, 1                  ; Arg 3: buffer length
int     080h
```

`edx` is meant to be the number of bytes to read and you have set it to `1` for some reason. That's not going to get your entire number, rather it will just get the first character of the first number.

On top of the input problems, there's a couple of problems there as well.

First, the statement:
    mov     eax, [m]
gets the *contents* of memory at `m`. If you're calling `atoi`, it will want the address itself.

Secondly, you need to examine your calling convention. The adding of values to `esp` seems very ... unusual to me. It *may* be correct but it doesn't seem to match any calling convention I've ever seen.

Comment: It's printing out the first converted string correctly, but hanging on the second atoi call now. Hopefully I can figure it out from here, thanks.

Comment: Also it only correctly prints if 4 or less digits are used as input, I need it so I can type 8 digits.

Comment: @tdwig, that's actually a _different_ question. The mechanism of SO is Q&A (with very specific answers to questions) rather than discussion board (chatting about various aspects tangentially related but not core to the original question), so you'll get a wider response of answers if you just post a new question (referring back to this one if you wish).